# Is this classed as a version of jobshop? How should it be approached?

Tags: scheduling, job-shop-scheduling

I'm looking at a problem that seems quite like flexible jobshop, but as I understand it jobshop is basically all about finding the order/sequence of tasks (across multiple machines potentially), however as far as I can tell it doesn't consider times. The problem I'm looking at has some jobs that will only be available to start at a specific time (earliest start time) and also may have their own deadlines for completion.

I could approach this just by setting constraints on those tasks not starting until t>earliest start time, but it seems like that would be potentially limiting?

Can anyone point me to what this may be called if its not a version of jobshop, or if it is jobshop how to best approach the differences?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. The (flexible) job-shop scheduling actually needs to have a specific route for each job. And these routes basically should be different for at least two jobs.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a job-shop variant. Usually we use the terms "release time" and "deadline". See the job characteristics list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_job_scheduling . The triplet notation there will help you search for papers that have similar job shop formulations. Adding the additional constraints is what you need to do; it will further reduce the feasible solution count but that shouldn't slow the (already slow) computation. Be sure to use the indicator constraint functions for the disjunctive constraints.